# Apache + PHP - Internal Server Error + (13)Permission denied

Tags: apache, php, webserver, sonoma

Trying to get php working on my localhost.

PHP has been code signed correctly and is running:

> AH06662: Allowing module loading process to continue for module at /opt/homebrew/opt/php@8.2/lib/httpd/modules/libphp.so because module signature matches authority "Mo" specified in LoadModule directive

Yet, when I try to open: /phpinfo.php I run into the following error:

> **Internal Server Error**
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at you@example.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

In errorlog I am seeing the following:

> [Thu Oct 26 16:40:53.069155 2023] [cgi:error] [pid 3910] [client ::1:52319] AH01215: (13)Permission denied: exec of '/Users/mo/Sites/1/phpinfo.php' failed: /Users/mo/Sites/1/phpinfo.php
> [Thu Oct 26 16:40:53.071058 2023] [cgi:error] [pid 3910] [client ::1:52319] End of script output before headers: phpinfo.php

Does (13)Permission denied mean that I need to `chmod +a "_www allow execute" ...` something to do with the PHP execution? macOS 14 is really making things complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I followed part of this tutorial on [Grav](https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-sonoma-apache-multiple-php-versions):

> Also you must set the Directory Indexes for PHP explicitly, so search for this block:

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>
```

> and replace it with this:

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

This seemed to solve my issues.